# How to decide the application name before launching to PlayStore

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

Is it possible to publish the application name same as already exist in the GooglePlay.?
How to check the availability of the application names.?
I want to launch application, before that i need confirmation like how we are check for the domain availability. is it possible.?
 suggest me your solutions

Comment: I think you should check for a conflicting package name too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as long you have different package you can publish apps with same name.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Application can have the same names , but it should differ from the package. Got it.

Comment: @user3706243 If this answer helped you, kindly select this answer and up vote it so that it can help others as well.